# Add Jogl documentation to User Library

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jar, jogl

I created Jogl 1.1 user library like the follow  -

[image]

It's work well but it hasn't documentation .

Which file should I point to its path under `gluegen-rt.jar >Javadoc location` and `jogl.jar >Javadoc location`  in order to get its documentation available in eclipse ?

note that when I press `Edit` under `JavaDoc location` I get the following -

[image]

so I have to know what to chose in these 2 text box `(Archive path` and `Path within archive`) .

Some relative resources -

http://jogamp.org/ - jogl home page   , the jars could be found under "build/Downloads"  .

[Downloading_and_installing_JOGL](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL) - there is "all platforms" version there  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which of the two jars you'll want to add this to, so try each in turn (or both), but adding this URL to where it says "Javadoc URL" in your second screenshot should do the trick:

http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/

If you have a local copy of the documentation however, use the browse button to navigate to it under "Javadoc in archive".

Comment: I think the one above is for jogl.jar, and this one is for gluegen: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/gluegen/javadoc/

Comment: thanks it work via URL  . About the archive file   , can you point me to the zip which has "Javadoc in archive" ? I can't find any such zip file .

Comment: The gluegen-javadoc and jogl-javadoc 7z files here should be the ones you want: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/